# What does “intestine enemy” mean?

Tags: expressions, adjectives

I’m particularly curious about the usage in Calvin’s commentary of Hebrews:

> ...at the same time we are carrying on war with sin, our intestine enemy.

However, [here](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22intestine+enemy%22) are some other examples.

Comment: You could use a [dictionary](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/intestine), and find the now-obsolete definition—"internal; specifically: of or relating to the internal affairs of a state or country *<intestine war>*". So he means "our enemy within ourselves".

Comment: *Intestine war* is a very common 17th century term for what we now usually call “civil war”.

Comment: @StoneyB _Internecine_ war is probably a closer approximation.

Comment: @coleopterist Or simply *internal*. Here’s both *civil wars* and *intestine wars* on the same [page](http://books.google.com/books?id=JvtCAAAAcAAJ&pg=PA66&dq=%22civil+war%22+%22intestine+war%22&hl=en&sa=X&ei=4xCMUKqEKdKDrQHoz4HICA&ved=0CD0Q6AEwAQ#v=onepage&q=%22civil%20war%22%20%22intestine%20war%22&f=false): *An History of the Civil VVars of England … Engliſhed by the Right Honourable Henry Earle of Monmouth … 1641*.